# live calculate script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

so first of all im kinda new to javascript and i cant make my script work when i put it on my site but it works in fiddle(because onload) i have the script in seperate file so here is how i have it now

script.js

```
var start = $('#calcstart'),
end = $('#calcend'),
brk = $('#calcbreak'),
total = $('#calcadded'),
timespan;

$('input').keyup(function () {
    var e = toMins(end.val()),
    s = toMins(start.val()),
    b = toMins(brk.val());
    if (!s || !e)
        return;
    var output = (e - s - b) / 60;
    total.html(Math.floor(output) + ':' + toDouble(Math.round((output % 1) * 60)));
});

function toMins(val) {
    if (!val)
        return 0;
    val = val.split(':');
    return (Number(val[0]) * 60) + Number(val[1] || 0);
}

function toDouble(n) {
    return n < 10 ? ('0' + n) : n;
}
```

livecalc.php

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Start:</td>
        <td><input id="calcstart" placeholder="hh:mm"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>end:</td>
        <td><input id="calcend" placeholder="hh:mm"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>break:</td>
        <td><input id="calcbreak" placeholder="hh:mm"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Total:</td>
        <td><span id="calcadded"></span></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/frilleee/3brha920/1/

so the question is how do i make this script work? how do i put it onload? or what should i do?

**Edit1 Okey i dont know how but it started work now dident change anything :S i have tested it for 2 days with the same code and not working :S**

Comment: **$(document).ready(function(){ //your code here });** ?

Comment: it doesent calculate(or work) when i try $(document).ready(function(){  });

Comment: Please show how you're using it and do you get an error in the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `script` tag like this

```
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

In your HTML. Save your script as 'script.js' and put script tag at the end inside `body` tag.

Like this.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>Start:</td><td><input id="calcstart" placeholder="hh:mm"></td></tr>
<tr><td>slut:</td><td><input id="calcend" placeholder="hh:mm"></td></tr>
<tr><td>rast:</td><td><input id="calcbreak" placeholder="hh:mm"></td></tr>
<tr><td>Total:</td><td><span id="calcadded"></span></td></tr>
</table>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Or

Put your whole script code inside `script` tag.

```
<script>
   // Your script here.
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For jQuery, you need to wrap your codes inside

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   // js and jquery codes in here
});
```

Read: https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Also, do you include your script.js file inside your HTML?
Check the Developer Tool > Console to find any other error related to javascript.